# Requisição POST em Swift não funciona

Tags: swift, post

Bom dia, procurei por diversos sites uma maneira de fazer uma requisição POST para um servidor, encontrei diversas formas e testei todas elas, mas nenhuma funcionou.
Eu consigo receber os dados da página e até mesmo enviar variáveis GET na URL, mas as variáveis POST simplesmente não são enviadas.

```
func teste(){

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://minhaurl/efetuarLogin.php?variavel=teste&get=valor")!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params = ["CPF":"00000000000", "senha":"12345678"] as Dictionary

    var err: NSError?

    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var err: NSError?

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        if((err) != nil) {

            println(err!.localizedDescription)

        } else {

            println("JSON: \(json)")

        }

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Na página PHP eu tento acessar as variáveis através da $_POST, $_GET e até mesmo $_REQUEST, apenas as variáveis GET são recebidas no servidor.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo de erro?
Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Como o que está sendo enviando é um **JSON**, com cabeçalho e tudo mais, não espere receber suas variáveis do lado do servidor (*CPF* e *senha*) como `$_POST['senha']` por exemplo, já que não foi um formulário que foi enviado.

Você precisa obter o "corpo" da requisição, que é um **JSON**, decodificar e então sim você terá as variáveis que necessita. No lado do servidor, com **PHP** tente algo assim:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

// $input['CPF'], $input['senha']
```

No *iOS* está tudo correto. Veja se isso resolve a sua questão.

Comment: O file_get_contents deve receber "php://input" mesmo ou devo colocar outra coisa? Dessa forma o retorno foi "<null>" :(

Comment: Sim. Antes foi possível você verificar o valor da variável `$inputJSON`?

Comment: Retornando o inputJSON obtive uma string vazia ""

Comment: Você tem acesso ao servidor para verificar se houve algum erro? Um ponto para lembrar, é que a função `file_get_contents` precisa da diretiva `allow_url_fopen` do PHP ativa.

Comment: Eu pensei logo de início que era algum bloqueio do servidor, mas o administrador garantiu que não havia bloqueio algum para esse endereço. As diretivas encontram-se da seguinte forma: 
allow_url_fopen: On; allow_url_include: Off; always_populate_raw_post_data: Off;

Comment: Bom, então nesse caso você precisa ver se o JSON está realmente indo na requisição. Notei que no seu código você não verificou se houve erro quando você usou o método `dataWithJSONObject`. Veja se a variável **err** possui erro. Eu costumo utilizar nas opções desse método o `.PrettyPrinted`. Isso pode causar um *malformed json*.

Comment: err e error (do método dataWithJSONObject) estão nulos (nil). Acha seguro passá-los via GET? A forma como estou fazendo, é segura? Via GET é bem mais fácil, se for seguro compensa muito mais fazer via GET, estou a muito tempo enroscado nisso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21898/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-mukotoshi).

Answer (score 0):

Na implementação que você postou não contem erros, é apenas um request bem simples.

Tente retirar os parâmetros da sua URL no request, pois pode estar sendo processado pelo servidor e ignorando o seu httpBody.

Comment: O código real não possui esses parâmetros, eu os coloquei aqui na pergunta para indicar que o envio variáveis GET funciona.